# Penalty of the MSVS compiler flag /bigobj

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

The basic Google search [bigobj issue](https://www.google.com/search?q=bigobj+issue) shows that a lot of people are experiencing the [Fatal Error C1128](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8578y171.aspx): "*number of sections exceeded object file format limit : compile with /bigobj*". The error has more chance to occur if one heavily uses a library of C++ templates, like [Boost libraries](http://www.boost.org) or [CGAL libraries](http://www.cgal.org/).

That error is strange, because it gives the solution to itself: set the [compiler flag `/bigobj`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173499.aspx)!

So here is my question: why is not that flag set by default? There must be a penalty of using that flag, otherwise it would be set by default. That penalty is not documented in MSDN. Does anybody have a clue?

I ask the question because I wonder if the configuration system of [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org) should not set `/bigobj` by default.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The documentation does mention an important drawback to `/bigobj`:

> Linkers that shipped prior to Visual C++ 2005 cannot read .obj files
>   that were produced with `/bigobj`.

So, setting this option by default would restrict the number of linkers that can consume the resulting object files. Better to activate it on a need-to basis.

Comment: It feels to me like this is only part of the answer. Why does this problem not occur with gcc or clang? Do they have the behavior of something similar to `/bigobj` directly built in and _always-on_?

Comment: @Ela782, mingw have the same problem with big object files. Need to set `-Wa,-mbig-obj` in this case. Probably, gcc create smaller .obj or have a larger size limit.

Comment: Its the PE-COFF object file format which has a 16-bit index to the section table, rather than overall object size.  The `/bigobj` option "kludges" this to a 32-bit index, but that wasn't supported pre-2005.  GCC toolchain faces the same limitations, hence `-Wa,-mbigobj` - but may do optimization differently.  On MSVC using string de-dup `/GF` (`/O1`, `/O2`) puts *each* string in its own section, which can dramatically increase section table size.

Comment: We're in 2020. 2005 is as far from today as 1990 was to 2005 when it was released. Did people in 2005 care about compatibility with MS-DOS 6-era linkers ? I pretty much doubt so.

Answer (score 7):

> why is not that flag set by default? There must be a penalty of using that flag, otherwise it would be set by default.

My quick informal experiment shows .obj files to be about 2% larger with `/bigobj` than without. So it's a small penalty but it's not zero.

Someone submitted a feature request to make `/bigobj` the default; see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Enable-bigobj-by-default/1031214.